# Is the binary .ipa not .zip on itunes connect?

Tags: file-format, app-store-connect

This is my first time to do Apple applications. I just uploaded the first game on itunes connect which I compressed the file under .zip on my local machine. After uploading to the iTunes Connect, I found out the binary file is .ipa not .zip. I don't know what happened.

Will Apple accept .ipa files? If not, how can I change the file from .ipa to .zip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.ipa is the correct file format to upload to Itunes connect.

Comment: Great.  Thanks for your quick reply.  I found out submit the app to apple store is harder than coding. :(

Answer (score 1):

A file with a .ipa file extension is simply a [ZIP archive with the extension renamed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ipa_%28file_extension%29).

Comment: Thank you.  You are great.  So with .ipa file extension on itunes connect should be ok, right?